# Адаптация скрипта с tkinter под Win+Anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.x, tkinter

Помогите, пожалуйста, адаптировать код скрипта на Python под Win + Anaconda.

Необходимо побороть ошибку.
В Linux работает код построения виджета `Combobox` из библиотеки Tkinter, а в Windows - нет.

Предварительно гуглил, но примеров работы с `Tk` через функцию `call` с `Combobox` не нашёл.

Код:

Инициализация:

```
def ui(im, nim, im_name):
    import Tkinter
    app = Tkinter.Tk()
    f = Tkinter.Frame(app)
    f.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nw")
    ...
```

Собственно, **проблемная функция** (к сожалению, ее писал не я):

```
def _optionmenu(k, v, *options):
    options = list(options)
    def trace(*args):
        try:
            var.set(options.index(svar.get()))
        except ValueError:
            pass

    try:
        opt = options[v]
    except (TypeError, IndexError):
        v = 0
        opt = options[0]

    var = Tkinter.IntVar(f)    
    var.set(v)
    svar = Tkinter.StringVar(f)
    svar.set(options[v])
    svar.trace("w", trace)
    wp = f._w.rstrip(".") + ".c" + svar._name
    f.tk.call("combobox::combobox", wp, "-editable", 0, "-width",
            max(len(opt) for opt in options)+3, "-textvariable", svar._name, "-background", "white")
    f.tk.call(wp, "list", "insert", "end", *options)
    w = nf.makewidget(f, Tkinter.Widget, wp)
    return w, var
```

Вызов:

```
def optionmenu(*options): return lambda f, v: _optionmenu(f, v, *options)

rc = os.path.expanduser("~/.image2gcoderc")
constructors = [
    ("units", optionmenu(_("G20 (in)"), _("G21 (mm)"))),
    ...
    ]

vars = {}
widgets = {}
for j, (k, con) in enumerate(constructors):
    v = defaults[k]
    text = texts.get(k, k.replace("_", " "))
    lab = Tkinter.Label(f, text=text)
    widgets[k], vars[k] = con(f, v)
    lab.grid(row=j, column=0, sticky="w")
    widgets[k].grid(row=j, column=1, sticky="ew")
```

**Ошибка при выполнении** строки:

```
f.tk.call("combobox::combobox", wp, "-editable", 0, "-width",....
```

> "TclError: invalid command name "combobox::combobox""

Тогда я её переписал так:

```
f.tk.call("ttk::combobox", wp, "-width",...
```

и получил ошибку в следующей строке:

```
f.tk.call(wp, "list", "insert", "end", *options)
```

> TclError: bad command "list": must be bbox, cget, configure, current, delete, get, icursor, identify, index, insert, instate, selection, state, set, validate, or xview

Не пойму что она от меня хочет, если в Linux выполнялось без проблем. 
Признаю, в Tkinter не силен.

Comment: Все таки осилил док-ю по Tk и решил проблема так: ValCbb = ""
        for w in options: ValCbb += '"'+w+'" '
        f.tk.call("ttk::combobox", wp, "-width",
                max(len(opt) for opt in options)+3, 
                "-textvariable", svar._name,
                "-background", "white",
                "-values", ValCbb)

Comment: и убрал за ненадобностью строку: f.tk.call(wp, "list", "insert", "end", *options)